# Vim: map rigth shift to Normal mode (escape)

Tags: vim, keyboard

After years of coding I'm finally learning Vim. My feeling is, it's all about muscular memory, making every move natural to suppress the bottleneck between the mind and the code.

In that spirit, my Escape key (XPS 15) is really not handy, in the mean time, Right Shift is literally the key I've used the less. And it's huge.

I'd like to map Right shift to Escape, either in vim or OS level (I'm on Ubuntu), I was unable to achieve that so far.

**EDIT**
(Thanks Ingo Karka) *I'm editing even if the question may not interest anyone, because I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one to struggle with XPS keyboard ESC key*. It may or may not be possible for right shift, that may not be a great idea though. **Switch ESC and CAP LOCKS** works just amazing.

Comment: Right shift, so you don't touch type? I would learn that first rather than thinking of these kind of remappings. A common target for remappings is the Caps Lock key; see [Map caps lock to escape in XWindows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows) for instructions. Some of those instructions can also be tweaked to use different keys, like the Right Shift you have in mind.

Comment: "Right shift, so you don't touch type" <= Seems like a great advice lies here, I didn't get the question though (maybe lost in translation, I'm French). Cap locks may work just fine, my <Esc> key is just too ridiculously tiny to turn its usage into a brainless automation.

Comment: I meant that for typing with all 10 fingers (vs. hunting around with just one or two fingers), you definitely will use both left and right shift keys; it's part of the process.

Comment: If case you'd like to try out my suggestion of swapping / using Caps Lock, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444714/how-do-i-swap-escape-and-caps-lock-in-14-04) shows that it's really easy in Ubuntu.

Comment: I do type with my 10 fingers, though for no reason I've always neglected right shift. Cap locks => Great advice, thanks. I've used that setup for only a couple of hours and it's already a brainless move.